# catch html window.open and the selected value using visual basic 2022

Tags: html, visual-studio-2022

**What I've done so far**

So what happens is, from this parent html page, I click a html button to open a new html page using window.open command and from this child html page, I select from table a value, send the value back to parent and close this child page.  This is doable on most browsers.  But I will be doing/opening this html pages on my created custom browser using visual basic 2022.

**With visual basic WebBrowser  control, my problems are:**

1. on html button click, it will open new default browser window and NOT on the WebBrowser control on new form and,
2. if the new html page on the WebBrowser control on the new opened child form, will the selected value will be passed to the parent WebBrowser.  I am not sure if it is default that window.opener on the child browser windows can pass the values to the parent browser window even in a custom browser.

**I need help on my following goals:**

1. I need to open the child html page using window.open to a WebBrowser control on a new visual basic form.
2. I need to pass the selected value from the child browser window to the parent browser window.

I am just a novice on vb.net programming and I have never done this WebBrowser NewWindow stuff on VB.